# Why does restarting MSMQ service cause queue journal messages to replay?

Tags: msmq

Win2k8 R2 sp1 - I have a WF service using AllowBufferedReceive over NetMsmqBinding.

The messages are journaled on the server at the WF service queue. If I restart the Message Queueing service, all journal messages are moved back to the active queues.

Why is this?